# Градиент из трех цветов полоской

Tags: градиент, style, css

Есть блок внутри него нужно сделать три градиента с жесткими переходами. т.е. должно быть три полосы. Пытался проделать получилось почи  так но переходы не жесткие.

```
#out{
background-color: #818286;
background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 15%, #5D5E62, #C6C6C6 48%);
}
```

Вот таким блок должен быть
http://cs617323.vk.me/v617323375/1456c/B3ixzeIeZT0.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте сервис [Colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Comment: Спасибо помогло.